# android studio jar file is red?

Tags: android, android-studio, localytics

I'm curious what's causing this? I'm picking up on someone's code and using a 3rd party analytics software called localytics. I'm trying to import their .jar file and had success when I created a dummy app with it. The problem is trying to integrate it with the current app. The previous developers had created their own implementation of the jar file that I cannot change (time sensitive).

Can anyone tell me why the .jar file is red in android studio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you have Version Control enabled for your current project and the Jar file is not added to the VCS.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the jar file in Android studio then choose "Add as Library" will solve this problem.